# Finding Documents Array CouchDB

Tags: arrays, find, couchdb

I have Documents they have this structure:

```
{id: ####,
rev: ####,
"Cam_name": "Camera SX",
"colour": "white",
"manufacturer": "Sony",
"rec_limit": 180,
"Customer": ["Mike","Ann","James"]
}

{id: ####,
rev: ####,
"Cam_name": "PXSV CAM",
"colour": "white",
"manufacturer": "LG",
"rec_limit": 144,
"Customer": ["Mike","Oliver","Mr. Rain"]
}

{id: ####,
rev: ####,
"Cam_name": "LxSV Double",
"colour": "white",
"manufacturer": "Phillips",
"rec_limit": 160,
"Customer": ["Mike"]
}
```

And i want to make an MAP Function query where i can see ALL Cam_Names which the Customer Mike is using.

i have a simillar Map Function but this shows only the Cam_Name LxSV Double and only the Customer Mike. i want to show all Cam_Names which mike is using.

MyQuery:

```
function(doc){
if(doc.Customer == "Mike"){
emit(doc.Cam_name, doc.Customer)
```

This query gives me not the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query looks *exactly* like that, then you have a syntax error. But also, `doc.Customer` is an array, so you can't do a simple equality check.

But checking the existence of a value in an array is totally unnecessary, your map function can simply look like this:

```
function (doc) {
  doc.Customer.forEach(function (customer) {
    emit(customer, doc.Cam_name);
  });
}
```

Then, query your view with `/{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}?key="Mike"`

Your output will look like:

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "####",
      "key": "Mike",
      "value": "Camera SX"
    },
    {
      "id": "####",
      "key": "Mike",
      "value": "PXSV CAM"
    },
    {
      "id": "####",
      "key": "Mike",
      "value": "LxSV Double"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, you can use this same view to find any customer, not just whomever you specify in your map function.

Comment: I'm only using futon.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Futon is an admin interface, it's not _really_ meant to be a general-purpose query tool. What version of CouchDB are you using? If you're on a fairly newer version, you can check out Futon's replacement, which is called [Fauxton](http://localhost:5984/_utils/fauxton/). It offers a way to add query-params when browsing views.

Comment: I'm using verison 1.6.1

do you know how can i build queries ? I read something with Node.js.. But it was to complicate. I never used javascript before. can you give me a short step by step introduction please ?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Question/Answer site, it's not a How-To site. I would encourage you to check out a site more dedicated to tutorials and how-to.

Comment: Thanks Dominic,

I saved my map function now. and how can i query my view with curl now ?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/intro.html)