# Querying a View with the key of an array using cURL

Tags: curl, view, couchdb

I have created a Map Function with Futon.  I saved my view as design document. I want to make a query with curl, where I want to see only special values of the array.

I'm using this to query:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/nameOfmyDatabase/_design/nameOfmyDoc/_view/nameOfmyView?key=\"Mike\"
```

If I run this command, it will give me the following message:

```
{"total_rows":320,"offset":0,"rows":[                                                 
]}
```

But I want to see all documents which are from Mike.  Mike is in the array.

I'm using windows machine.

Comment: Maybe try a different enclosing of your command: `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/nameOfmyDatabase/_design/nameOfmyDoc/_view/nameOfmyView?key="Mike"'`.

Comment: It doe's not work :s aaaaaaa. 

It returns the following massage:
error bad request reason invalid json

Comment: You should include at least 1 sample document, it's difficult to help without one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169656/finding-documents-array-couchdb/29171908#29171908

this was my question before

Comment: @Relaxo Does your view function contain this code? `emit(doc.Customer[0], ....);`

Comment: my design document looks like:

function(doc) {
doc.customer.forEach(function (customer){
emit(doc.customer, doc.Cam_name);});}

Comment: okey okey i fixed my problem :)

my view must look like:

function (doc) {
  doc.Customer.forEach(function (customer) {
    emit(customer, doc.Cam_name);
  });
}

And the query for the view ?key=\"Mike\" because i'm using cmd mode on windows

Comment: is there any other samples to treat array. Other options. what can i do with my arrays ?